# How can i render a 3D image in android?

Tags: android, image, 3d, render

I have a client who works on styling cars, he needs an app that lets the user take several pictures of their car and render 1 3d image he can use to look around the car. Is there any way to do this? I have been searching for methods but can't find a solution.

Comment: may be these will help: http://ramsrigoutham.com/2012/12/21/panorama-app-on-android-using-stitching-module-opencv/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618044/stitching-2-images-opencv

Comment: Rendering a 3D object is very possible, however constructing a 3D model of something from a series of pictures is no small feat. If the latter is what you want to do, I'd suggest changing your title.

Comment: @NathanWalters could you point me in the direction to construct a 3d model from pictures?

Comment: @MoussaHarajli I have absolutely no idea how to go about doing that.